# swift 3 a function not being called

Tags: swift

When I tap the `addFavoriteButton` everything is called except for the `fav.tableview.insertRows` function, it doesn't crash or gives me an error, but its not being called, because the first thing it should do if its called is to print something in the console.

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {



   // var favorites: favorites!
    var store: Store!

    var copiedarray = [String]()

    var wrds: manager_class = manager_class()
    var fav: favorites = favorites()
    //var historyObject: historyTableView = historyTableView()




    @IBOutlet var addFavoriteButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var favorite: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet var TranslationLanguages: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var translationLangTest: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

    let arabic = ["مادي", "بسيط", "معقد", "سيارة"]
    let english = ["Concrete", "Simple", "Complex", "Car"]
    let french = ["Concret", "Simple", "Comlexe", "Car"]

    let languages = ["Pick a language","English to Arabic" , "English to French" , "Arabic to English" , "Arabic to French" , "French to English" , "French to Arabic"]




    @IBAction func addFavoriteButton(_ sender: Any) {

        print(SearchBar.text!)
        if (SearchBar.text?.isEmpty)! {
            return
        }
        for item in wrds.favorite_words {
            if item == SearchBar.text {
                print("item is already in favorite!")
                return
            }

        }

        wrds.favorite_words.append(SearchBar.text!)
        //print(wrds.favorite_words)
        let newItem = wrds.favorite_words.last


        if let index = wrds.favorite_words.index(of: newItem!) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            fav.tableView.beginUpdates()
            fav.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            fav.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
```

class favorites: UITableViewController {

```
var wrds1: manager_class = manager_class()

var store: Store!

//var tableCell = TableViewCell()
var copiedarray1 = [String]()
//let cell1: TableViewCell = TableViewCell()



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("i am inside table view!")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    print(wrds1.favorite_words.isEmpty)
    print("Heloo")


    let word = wrds1.favorite_words[indexPath.row]
    cell.favoriteWordInTable?.text = word


    return cell
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return copiedarray1.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let title = "favorites"
    return title
}
override func viewDidLoad() {


    let wrds: ViewController = ViewController()
    //let wrds1: manager_class = manager_class()

    copiedarray1 = wrds.copiedarray



}
```

}

Comment: If you breakpoint inside the if condition and it's not stopped over there, that means the wrds.favorite_words.index(of: newItem!) is nil. Just try to `po wrds.favorite_words.index(of: newItem!)` in the console and check the result.

Comment: i tried to breakpoint, it goes inside the if statement and it goes over all of the functions inside, insertRows is not working, its not inserting new rows.

Comment: what's `favorites`?

Comment: i will edit the post and add my favorites class

Comment: You also need to follow swift coding conventions. Your classes, structs, enums and protocols needs to be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: i'll probably clean my code when i am done with it, but now i am trying to fix this issue, its not adding any rows to the favorite tableView.

Comment: I see you're having 1 `UIViewController`, and the other is a `UITableViewController`. And you want to change number of `tableView` cells from within your `ViewController`. But you're not doing it right. That's becuase you initialize a new object of the `favorites` in (`var fav: favorites = favorites()`).
There're many ways to update the tableView depening on your use case. You can use protocols with delegates. or probably use set `self` when you init the viewController from `favorites`
You need to provide more info on your use case to get help on the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Point your mouse cursor at the left of your function to be called, there should be a round dot, if your button is connected to this function, when you click the dot, you should see the button shown in the popup list.

Your problem should be the connection between the code and the storyboard, or only on the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `wrds.copiedarray` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

And `wrds1.favorite_words` in `cellForRow`.

I think you have to change the `numberOfRowsInSection` like this :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wrds1.favorite_words.count
}
```